# Hierarchy Data shift

Tags: java, hierarchical-data

After running a recursive function to obtain an employee/manager family tree - a further requirement has come up to reserve an overall manager structure.

So I would imagine the input array to look something like this

```
[["Employee A", "1000", "Employee B", "1001", "Employee C", "1002"],
["Employee D", "1003", "Employee C", "1002"]]
```

and the output array would need to look like this

```
[["Employee A", "1000", "Employee B", "1001", "Employee C", "1002"],
["Employee D", "1003", null, null, "Employee C", "1002"]]
```

The hierachy needs to be sorted in this manner to show that Employee C retains the role of senior manager at all times

```
public void refactorArray(String jsonData) throws Exception {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonData);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

        //flag previous position of grandfather manager and name/id

        // if previous position does not match current position - do logic to pop the array at that element to put it back into the previous position
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain how these list contain information about a tree.

Comment: Employee A and D are rookies. Employee B is a manager and Employee C is like the big boss. The "null" entries that need to be inserted will retain that although Employee C directly manages Employee D - Employee C is in the position of big boss always

Comment: is the height of your "tree" always 2? and the `C` will  be always the (only) root of the "tree"?

Comment: this is a simplified version. Generally though I think you will have a big boss that is the root of the treet, but there will be more sub-level managers.

Comment: I am not sure that the question "is widely applicable to a large audience" - I have never seen this way of representing trees before, specially if JSON is available to build an actual hierarchical structure...

Comment: What is a "multiple ruler"? Can you provide example input/output by editing the question?

Comment: Its a case of finding the longest element first - using it as a rule - but then when it stumbles on another long element to use that as a rule too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the idea of finding the longest one first, and taking it as reference for future boss-padding, yields the following code, which works fine for the case above.

The idea is to build a 'bosses' lookup table, built from the longest leaf-to-root path we find. Whenever we have a boss that is in the lookup table, we make sure that he appears in the same position as he appears in the longest path, padding with nulls as necessary.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class T {
    static String refactor(String jsonData) {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonData);

        // find longest array in original container
        JSONArray longest = null;
        for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray a = array.getJSONArray(i);
            if (longest == null || a.length() > longest.length()) {
                longest = a;
            }
        }

        // build a map with the people in "longest", for quick lookup
        HashMap<String, Integer> bosses = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<longest.length(); i+=2) {
            bosses.put(longest.getString(i) + "|" + longest.getString(i+1), i);
        }

        // prepare target container       
        ArrayList<JSONArray> container = new ArrayList<JSONArray>();

        // fill in missing values
        for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray a = array.getJSONArray(i);
            ArrayList<String> refactored = new ArrayList<String>();
            // copy leaf employee
            refactored.add(a.getString(0));
            refactored.add(a.getString(1));
            for (int j=2; j<a.length(); j+=2) {
                // possibly fill in nulls before adding this boss
                String boss = a.getString(j) + "|" + a.getString(j+1);
                if (bosses.containsKey(boss)) {
                    for (int k=j; k<bosses.get(boss); k++) {
                        // pad with nulls until we reach target position
                        refactored.add(null);
                    }
                }
                refactored.add(a.getString(j));
                refactored.add(a.getString(j+1));
            }
            container.add(new JSONArray(refactored));
        }
        return new JSONArray(container).toString();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(refactor(args[0]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two loops,

Loop1: find the longest array in the wrapper array. It would be the complete path from lowest position to big boss. Take this as the ruler. There could be more than one longest array, depending on your requirements.

Loop2: for each array, compare elements with the rule we found, when a unmatched element was found, add a null (or two Nulls with ID) element.

btw, List would be better Datastructure than array(s) for this problem.

input:

```
a-b-c-d-e-f
x-c-e
y-b-d-f
```

1st step you found `a-b-c-d-e-f`

then compare `x-c-e` to it in each element from the 2nd element, you get `x-null-c-null-e-null`

Comment: Thats a good idea. So Loop1 - will set the entire hierarchy employee/manager levels. For Loop 2 - if the situation were more complex where Employee C is found at position [5] and then position [2] - is it a case of sorting the array to ensure that Employee C is relocated to [5]? What information from rule would be used to help make a match or not?

Comment: What information do I get from loop 1 - apart from acquiring the longest length of a nested array

Comment: In loop 2, how would I use the rule accordingly - as each row may contain different managers, sub managers. Would I start to compare the elements within the rule to see if their positions have changed?

Comment: @TheOldCounty added a small example.

Comment: then compare y-b-d-f to it in each element from the 3rd element, you get y-b-null-d-null-f

Comment: @TheOldCounty if the first node is always the lowest, comparison starts from 2nd. Otherwise you have to find the index in the found ruler and add leading null nodes.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to how to go about doing this all in code

Comment: ^ please check the development code below - is the logic correct to your solution

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y74z42ms/15/ - I've made this - but the null placements are not correct - what is wrong with the logic?

Comment: If its likely I need to capture multiple rulers - what logic would I apply to switch or increment over to another one to keep the dataset consistent?

Comment: I've implemented something very similar to this approach in Java - and it works for these scenarios. "Multiple rules" would be ambiguous, as there would be cases where more than one answer would fit.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first loop - it seems to provide the rule correctly. I've written in javascript here -

************** LATEST CODE ********************* 17/04/2015

http://jsfiddle.net/y74z42ms/25/

For loop 2 - am I to loop through each array element and rule - and if so what logic is applied to insert a null entry?

--- does this look correct?

```
var input = [
    ["AaronG", "RupertJ", "ScottK", "DannyC", "LennyD"],
    ["JackieP", "RupertJ", "ScottK", "DannyC", "LennyD"],
    ["NelsaI", "SamJ", "ScottK", "DannyC", "LennyD"],
    ["BrentD", "SamJ", "ScottK", "DannyC", "LennyD"],
    ["MaryS", "CardinalE", "DannyC", "LennyD"],
    ["GaroleP", "CardinalE", "DannyC","LennyD"],
    ["AlanA", "ChanA", "KopecK", "LennyD"],
    ["GerryA", "ChanA", "KopecK", "LennyD"],
    ["BurlS", "TodD", "KopecK", "LennyD"],
    ["KenS", "TodD", "KopecK", "LennyD"],
    ["JerryU", "JasonA", "JefferyW", "MargotS", "LennyD"],
    ["BakerI", "JasonA", "JefferyW", "MargotS", "LennyD"]
];
console.log("input", input);
$('#in').html(input.toString());

//:loop1
var ruleStorage = [];
var rule = null;
var lastRule = null;
for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    //count the nested array elements - store it if its the longest
    rule = input[i];
    if (lastRule != null) {
        if (lastRule.length > rule.length) {
            rule = lastRule;
        } 
            ruleStorage.push(rule);    
    }
    lastRule = rule;
}

ruleStorage = $.unique(ruleStorage); //provides unique rules
//:loop1


//:loop2
//use rule 1
console.log("ruleStorage", ruleStorage);
rule = ruleStorage[0];
var output = [];
for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    //count the nested array elements - store it if its the longest
    var nestedEl = input[i];
    var newNest = [];
    //compare nestedEl with rule - and use the rule to insert null spaces accordingly

    //create null entries first
    for (j = 0; j < rule.length; j++) {
        newNest[j] = null;
    }

    //loop through the rule and compare
    for (j = 0; j < rule.length; j++) {
        var originalPos = rule.indexOf(rule[j]);
        var currentPos = nestedEl.indexOf(rule[j]);

        //build the new nest
        //if its in the original postion restore it as such
        if (originalPos == currentPos) {
            newNest[j] = nestedEl[j];
        }

        //element is new and doesn't exist in the rule
        if (
        currentPos == -1 && originalPos != -1 && rule.indexOf(nestedEl[j]) == -1 && nestedEl[j] !== undefined) {
            newNest[originalPos] = nestedEl[j];
        }

        //element is not new but its in the wrong place
        if (
        rule.indexOf(nestedEl[j]) != -1 && nestedEl[j] !== undefined) {
            var rulePos = rule.indexOf(nestedEl[j]);
            newNest[rulePos] = nestedEl[j];
        }

    }
    //console.log("newNest", newNest);
    //console.log("nestedEl", nestedEl);

    output.push(newNest);

}
console.log("output", output);

$('#out').html(output.toString());
//:loop2
```

Comment: The code falls down if there are 2nd level managers which don't appear in the rule. You mentioned that its likely multiple rules will be needed - should I try and batch up rules which are fully listed and contain the max number of elements. This seems very complex - how I would adapt the code to record multiple rules and to do comparison checks against those rules

Comment: The results become skewered when it stumbles on "KopecK" - its as if I either need to switch over to the next rule - or the results again against the next rule

Comment: I've tried wrapping it into a function - and passing the output through again and again with the longest found rules in sequence. -- but no affect. http://jsfiddle.net/y74z42ms/26/

Comment: Problem comes from KopecK - not being part of a rule - and so their initial placement as a senior manager is a miss